# ¿Qué parte de una frase se pone entre signos de exclamación?

Tags: gramática, puntuación

Estaba leyendo la noticia [Marc Márquez: “No sabía lo que era la presión hasta este año”](http://deportes.elpais.com/deportes/2016/10/16/actualidad/1476635015_239768.html) en la que un piloto de motocicletas narra cómo ganó la carrera (y, por ende, el Mundial) cuando esta parte captó mi atención:

> La segunda caída, la de Lorenzo, que le convertía en campeón, le hizo volverse loco. "Metí tercera en curvas donde debía ir en segunda, cuarta donde debía ir en quinta… Y al final tuve que espabilar, **que ¡Dovizioso estaba acercándose!**"

Como veis, la parte de *Dovizioso estaba acercándose* está marcada entre signos de exclamación. Esquemáticamente, está diciendo:

```
Hice X, que ¡estaba pasando Y!
            ^
```

Yo intuitivamente habría incluido *que* en la exclamación:

```
Hice X, ¡que estaba pasando Y!
        ^
```

Hice un poco de introspección y vi que no tenía argumento que sustentara mi hipótesis, por lo que le pregunté al Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, que en el artículo sobre [exclamación](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=exclamaci%C3%B3n) dice:

> d) Los signos de apertura (¿ ¡) se han de colocar justo donde empieza la pregunta o la exclamación, aunque no se corresponda con el inicio del enunciado; en ese caso, la interrogación o la exclamación se inician con minúscula (→ mayúsculas, 3.4.2b):
>
> *Por lo demás, ¿qué aspecto tenía tu hermano?*
>
> *Si encuentras trabajo, ¡qué celebración vamos a hacer!*

Esto me hace pensar que mi idea es buena, pero no me lo confirma. ¿Cuál es el criterio pues para estos casos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El criterio es precisamente ese: colocar los signos de exclamación donde quieres que empiece la misma. El ejemplo que has puesto no es más que una forma un tanto inusual de decir lo siguiente:

> Y al final tuve que espabilar, porque... ¡Dovizioso estaba acercándose!

Si te fijas, también puedes exclamarlo así:

> Y al final tuve que espabilar, que Dovizioso ¡estaba acercándose!
>
> Y al final tuve que espabilar, porque Dovizioso... ¡estaba acercándose!

Y si me apuras:

> Y al final tuve que espabilar, que Dovizioso estaba ¡acercándose!
>
> Y al final tuve que espabilar, porque Dovizioso estaba... ¡acercándose!

Cualquiera de los ejemplos es perfectamente válido, todo depende de dónde quiere el escritor que se comience la inflexión de la exclamación al pronunciar (o de reflejar dónde comenzó la inflexión la persona que está citando). Es la ventaja de disponer de un signo de apertura de exclamación: te da más poder y flexibilidad en la narrativa para reflejar cuál es la parte sorprendente de la frase.

Comment: Entonces el DPD nos deja con la incógnita de qué es exactamente esto de _donde empieza la pregunta o la exclamación_. Para mí, es donde hago la inflexión cuando lo pronuncio. En el caso de la noticia, para mí el _que_ sí sería parte, pero como bien indicas en tu respuesta esto puede tener tantas versiones como palabras, prácticamente.

Comment: @fedorqui creo que se refiere a cuando empieza la pregunta o exclamación en el diálogo, es decir, en la expresión oral. Se refiere, como dices, a cuando comienza la inflexión al pronunciar. También sirve para delimitar la parte sorprendente. Si ya estabas hablando de Dovizioso previamente, puedes dejarlo fuera de la exclamación, y dejar dentro solo lo de que se estaba acercando. La imaginación es el límite.

Comment: Sin embargo, ¿no te pasa a ti que antes de empezar la inflexión haces una pequeña pausa? A mí sí y poner el signo de exclamación tras el _que_ me genera un sonido algo postizo.

Comment: @fedorqui no exactamente, más bien al contrario: si leo la frase del artículo me parece inusual la redacción, pero la pronunciaría metiendo la inflexión de la exclamación de forma gradual, sin hacer una pausa pero tampoco iniciando la inflexión de golpe.